# Hybris task engine stopped

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I upgraded recently to hybris 2005. And for some reason, the tasks are not being executed, they get stuck at running state. If I access /processing it says:

```
Welcome to "processing" extension
Task engine status: stopped
```

I already checked all the properties related to tasks engine, I have the following values:

```
task.processing.enabled=true
task.engine.loadonstartup=true
```

On logs I can't see any info related to business process, task engine, etc...

Any tips here?

Comment: can you please share some screenshots to understand the problem in a better way?
I did migration on the same version but it's working fine.

Comment: I am not sure what to attach since there is no log info. The business process are just stucked.

Comment: Did you try debug for task engine?